How to compile .can files to an executable via CLI without using CAPL Browser for automation?
I have a set of .can files that I need to compile into executables as part of an automation workflow for work. The files are prepared for compilation in CAPL Browser, but I want to automate this process without using CAPL Browser directly.
The goal is to create a program that can:
Download the .can files from the internet.
Compile them via CLI or a script (e.g., using a bash file or some other scripting approach).
Generate an executable file that I can use in further automation steps.
I've already managed to download the files, but I'm stuck on the compilation step to produce an executable. I've looked online but haven’t found a clear solution on how to automate this compilation.
Any suggestions on tools, libraries, or command-line processes that would help me compile .can files without manual steps? Ideally, I need a process or script that I can integrate into my automation.

CAPL files are always compiled within a certain context. E.g. bus node, test module, test table, etc. What you can do is - via COM - load a CANoe configuration and compile it, which will compile the CAPL files. Wheter this is the way to go is hard to tell as you do not give any details about your use case.
